# Small issue with jCarousel Lite

Tags: jquery, carousel, jcarousellite

I am using this http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/ for vertical slider.

Now the settings i have is:

```
var sliderShowItems = $(.vSlider).attr('id').split('-', 2);

$('.vSlider').jCarouselLite({
            visible: sliderShowItems[1],
            scroll: sliderShowItems[1],
            auto: 6000,
            speed: 650,
            vertical: true,
            pauseOnHover: false         
});
```

Now the problem is that I want to get amount of visible items from CMS dynamically (hence the var sliderShowItems), but jCaroulseLite breaks if I do it like that. It only shows the the first 4 (if I have put 4 in my cms) and then just starts to scroll randomly. If I just put for example visible: 4 and scroll: 4 it works fine. But when I put the number dynamically like this it breaks up :( And Im not sure why? Any advice?

Comment: If it works when you hard-code the number in there, then maybe `sliderShowItems[1]` is not getting the value you intended. Either way, `visible` and `scroll` are getting the _same_ value right?

Comment: When I consolge log / alert the sliderShowItems variable it shows the correct number. And yes I want visible and scroll to have same value.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what value you're getting from sliderShowItems, are you trying to show more images if there are more images? because you can try something like.

```
var sliderShowItems = $(.vSlider).length;
sliderShowItems = Math.ceil(sliderShowItems / 3);

$('.vSlider').jCarouselLite({
            visible: sliderShowItems,
            scroll: sliderShowItems,
            auto: 6000,
            speed: 650,
            vertical: true,
            pauseOnHover: false         
});
```

Comment: Totally have had the same issue before, I resolved it with PHP though. +1 for using `Math.ceil()`!

Comment: When I console log / alert the sliderShowItems variable it shows the correct number. But I'll try it with math.ceil.

And no, I want admin to be able to control from CMS how many items there are and how manyitems are shown on one "panel".

@mmmshuddup could you tell more on how you did on PHP? I think I could do it that way too.

Comment: If you are allowing the user to control it with cms i would imagine you're using a database. why not just save the about to slide and the amount to show in a table in the DB then just echo the variables in the JavaScript with php

Comment: Hmm, thats possible as well. But not sure does it actually help at all. Will try. The math.ceil didnt help btw (the values very excact values already).

Comment: what is the value of $(.vSlider).attr('id'), just wondering why that would be good to use for the number visible and the number to scroll

Comment: From $(.vSlider).attr('id') comes scoll-X (x being the value that admin has set in CMS).